# Checking statement or assignation variable for performance?

Tags: java, android, c++, c, performance

What is the instruction which takes more time between a `if()` or a variable initialization ?

Will it be more efficient to first check whether a given variable has a non-zero value and set it only if it was nonzero?

for example : a boolean !

```
if (boolean)
    boolean = false;
```

or directly : `boolean = false;`

Comment: Surely it is obvious that X+Y > X unless Y is zero (or negative)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Most likely it is faster to NOT check. It does depend on the type of the object being set (in this case, a boolean, which clearly is "simple to set"). Only particularly special objects that have "simple compare" and "complex to set" would benefit from checking first.

And if it really is that easy to check and hard to change, then the "set" function should check that itself.

An exception would be shared memory between processors where there is a lot of contention, since writing to the memory will force the caches of the other processors to be flushed, which takes time.